# mySQL Between Time Range - Where start time can be greater than end time

Tags: mysql, datetime, time

I tried searching SO for this question and couldn't find anything related to mySQL.

I have a table that holds various data but for this question, the relevant data is the day of week, start time and end time.

I'm trying to get the records that match a day of the week where now() is within the matching time range. However, the catch is the start time CAN be greater than the end time or vice versa or the time could also just be 00:00:00.

Relevant fields and example data for table `page_data`:

```
field_value | start_time | end_time
------------+------------+---------
Monday      | 17:00:00   | 08:00:00
Tuesday     | 17:00:00   | 08:00:00
Wednesday   | 17:00:00   | 08:00:00
Thursday    | 17:00:00   | 08:00:00
Friday      | 17:00:00   | 08:00:00
Saturday    | 00:00:00   | 00:00:00
Sunday      | 00:00:00   | 00:00:00
```

**A few notes:**

- 00:00:00 - 00:00:00 basically means run all day
- if start time is greater than end time, like 17:00 - 8:00 that would
  mean to run from 5pm to 8am on the next day.

I tried `now() between start_time and end_time` but that doesn't cover start_time > end_time.

Below is what I have so far but it returns when it shouldn't.

10:00:00 is a test time that shouldn't return anything but it does.

For testing I'm hard coding a time instead of using `now()`

if I remove `or ('10:00:00' between end_time and start_time)` then start_time being greater won't return anything.

```
select * from page_data
where field_value = 'Friday'
and (
    (start_time = '00:00:00' and end_time = '00:00:00') or
    ('10:00:00' between start_time and end_time) or
    ('10:00:00' between end_time and start_time)
)
```

I'm stumped on the query that I can use to take into these considerations:

- Start Time > End Time
- End Time > Start Time
- End Time && Start Time = 00:00:00

Thank you

Comment: What does it mean in your data set when end_time < start_time?  Does that mean the recorded event started on one day and ended the next?  Why is midnight for start and end a special case?  What does it mean in the data set?

Comment: @pilcrow I apologize for lack of context. This table is for a website to determine when a notice should show. The default value actually just converts to 00:00:00 and is really just a very specific use case for this project. That part I know I do other stuff with like having the default value NULL etc. I'm more caught up on start time being greater than end time and vice versa. I didn't store datetime objects as these aren't specific to a date.

Comment: So, does `('Weds', '17:00', '08:00')` mean that the notice should show from Weds. at 5pm until _the next day_ at 8am?  And double-midnight means, "always show" on the given day?  It'd be helpful to show example values and what rows you expect to be selected.

Comment: @pilcrow thank you for your edit and question. You are right on your assumptions and I did clarify those things on the question.

Comment: So if start_time > end_time, is the correct logic that NOW() should NOT be between end_time and start_time?

Comment: This logic would be easier to express if you changed the data (created a VIEW?) so that "all day" windows were specified as `start_time = '00:00:00'` with `end_time = '23:59:59'`.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using `hours` to define how many hours from `start_time`. For example if `start_time='17:00:00'` and `end_time='08:00:00'` so, you have a column named like `process_hour` at `15`. Then do something like `'10:00:00' between start_time + INTERVAL process_hour HOUR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the situation where start_time > end_time, I'm guessing you only want to match if test_time is greater than start_time, or less than end_time.  This is logically equivalent to test_time NOT between end_time and start_time.

If this logic is correct, this code might be what you need:

```
select * from page_data
where field_value = 'Friday'
and (
    (start_time = '00:00:00' and end_time = '00:00:00') or
    (start_time < end_time) and ('10:00:00' between start_time and end_time) or
    (start_time > end_time) and NOT('10:00:00' between end_time and start_time)
)
```

Comment: Oh wow that works thank you. I was so focused on it being between, that I never thought of the opposite.

Comment: This will [return a match for Monday 7:30a.m.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/632f51/14), which is not what the data say.

Answer (score 0):

Would you prefer this?

```
SELECT ...
  FROM easier_to_work_with
 WHERE day_of_week = DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE)
       AND
       CURRENT_TIME BETWEEN start_time AND end_time;
```

It seems to me it'd be easier to work with "notice window" periods specified as time intervals *confined to a single day*, representing windows that span more than one day as two adjacent windows.

Then you simply check the current day and current time against the windows.

You can do this without changing existing application logic or existing table structure:

```
CREATE VIEW easier_to_work_with AS
     -- get same day windows
     SELECT ..., field_value as day_of_week, start_time, end_time
       FROM page_data
      WHERE start_time < end_time
      UNION
     -- get all day windows, or partials crossing midnight
     SELECT ..., field_value, start_time, '23:59:59'
       FROM page_data
      WHERE (start_time = '00:00:00' AND end_time = '00:00:00')
              OR
            end_time < start_time
      UNION
     -- get carryover windows from the previous day
     SELECT ...,
            CASE field_value
              WHEN 'Monday'    THEN 'Tuesday'
              WHEN 'Tuesday'   THEN 'Wednesday'
              WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 'Thursday'
              WHEN 'Thursday'  THEN 'Friday'
              WHEN 'Friday'    THEN 'Saturday'
              WHEN 'Saturday'  THEN 'Sunday'
              WHEN 'Sunday'    THEN 'Monday'
            END, '00:00:00', end_time
       FROM page_data
      WHERE end_time < start_time;
```